# Error: deleted_client while logging with Google

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, keycloak

I am getting the below error while login with google through Keycloak.
401. That’s an error.

> Error: deleted_client
>
> The OAuth client was deleted.
>
> Request Details That’s all we know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application you are using has a client id created via google developers console.   The client id in question was deleted your going to have to create a new client id and recompile your application.

That is assuming this "keyCloak" is your own application if not then you should contact the developer of the application they have a problem

Comment: Is there a way to see when the account was deleted? I have a similar issue but I haven't found a log that tells me who deleted